# Javascript: updating a field in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript function `replaceOrAdd` which takes on Object and an Array of objects.

It should use the fields in the Object to update fields in the matching object in the Array parameter. The matching object in the array is the one with the same value for rowId.

If there are no matching objects in the array, it should add it.

Example:

```
var anArray = [
 {rowId:0, a:0, b:5, c:2},
 {rowId:1, a:12, b:7, c:2.5}
];
var anObject= {rowId:1, b:9999};
var result = replaceOrAdd(anObject, anArray);
```

Wanted result:

```
[
  {rowId:0, a:0, b:5, c:2},
  {rowId:1, a:12, b:9999, c:2.5}
]
```

Actual result:

```
[
  {rowId:0, a:0, b:5, c:2},
  {rowId:1, a:12, b:7, c:2.5}
]
```

My function:

```
function replaceOrAdd(anObject, anArray) {

    if (anObject==null) {
        return anArray;
    }

    let arrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(anArray));
    let found = anArray.find(s => s.rowId===anObject.rowId);
    if (found) {
        Object.assign(found, anObject);
    } else {
        arrayCopy.push(anObject);
    }

    return arrayCopy;
}
```

I have found that `Object.assign()` is working as expected but array is not reflecting the changed field. How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: why are you creating a copy is that needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be calling `find` on the copy of the array (`arrayCopy`), not the original:

```js
function replaceOrAdd(anObject, anArray) {

    if (anObject==null) {
        return anArray;
    }

    let arrayCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(anArray));
    let found = arrayCopy.find(s => s.rowId===anObject.rowId);
    if (found) {
        Object.assign(found, anObject);
    } else {
        arrayCopy.push(anObject);
    }

    return arrayCopy;
}


var anArray = [
 {rowId:0, a:0, b:5, c:2},
 {rowId:1, a:12, b:7, c:2.5}
];
var anObject= {rowId:1, b:9999};
var result = replaceOrAdd(anObject, anArray);

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{max-height:100%!important;top:0}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks. (feeling foolish) I will accept your answer when the 10 minutes is up.

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the change to an object in the original array and not the (deep) copy.

Change `anArray.find` to `arrayCopy.find`.

Answer (score 0):

This is more easier in ES6

```js
const replaceOrAdd = (anObject, anArray) => {

    if (anObject==null) {
        return anArray;
    }

    let arrayCopy = [...anArray];
    let index = arrayCopy.findIndex(s => s.rowId===anObject.rowId);
    if (index !== -1) {
        arrayCopy[index] = {...arrayCopy[index], ...anObject}
    } else {
        arrayCopy.push(anObject);
    }

    return arrayCopy;
}

let anArray = [
 {rowId:0, a:0, b:5, c:2},
 {rowId:1, a:12, b:7, c:2.5}
];
var anObject= {rowId:1, b:9999};
var result = replaceOrAdd(anObject, anArray);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Elegant ES6 solution. It may admit multiple objects with the same rowId.

```js
function replaceOrAdd(obj, arr) {
    if (!obj)  return arr;
    const found = arr.find(x => obj.rowId === x.rowId);
    const replaced = arr.map(x => obj.rowId === x.rowId ? Object.assign(x, obj) : x);
    const appended = [...arr, obj];
    return found ? replaced : appended;
}

var anArray = [
    {rowId:0, a:0, b:5, c:2},
    {rowId:1, a:12, b:7, c:2.5}
];
console.log(0, replaceOrAdd(null, anArray));
console.log(1, replaceOrAdd({rowId: 1, b: 9999}, anArray));
console.log(2, replaceOrAdd({rowId: 2, b: 9999}, anArray));
```

Comment: It would be even more elegant - and less problematic - if it'd declare local variables ;)

Comment: I indeed thought the same. It's been edited now. :)

Comment: Hmm... What exactly did you mean by "local variables" then? I've been referencing to found ? replaced : appended;

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I don't see any `const`/`let`/`var` for them...

Comment: Oh right dude, absolutely!! I've been way too used to Ruby recently...
It's been updated, thanks for the note. :)